# creating subscription with laravel cashier

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

Documentation lists this example:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')->create($creditCardToken);
```

> The create method will begin the subscription as well as update your database with the customer ID and other relevant billing information.

Does anyone know where do I get $creditCardToken from? I am using Braintree and perhaps this example is for Stripe?

Comment: There's not really enough information here for us to understand what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

Ps. I have no reputation to comment yet.

On Braintree doc (https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/create/php) it do not ask for a Credit Card Token.

Which kind of error do you get if you do not pass any argument to create?